# Linear but discontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, epsilon-delta

Consider  $\mathcal C^0$ = {$f : (0, 1) → \mathbb R$ | f is continuous} and $E_{\beta}(f) = f(\beta)$, for $\beta \in (0,1)$, and the metric
$$ d(f,g) = ||f-g||_2 = \sqrt{\int_0^1(f(x) - g(x))^2dx}$$.

I want to check whether $E_{\beta}$ is discontinuous for all $\beta$. This would mean, I need $d(f,g) < \delta$ (that is, the area between f and g to be arbitrarily low) but $d(f(\beta),g(\beta))$ to be equal to some constant, say 1.

Is it possible for two functions f and g to have a 'small' area between their graphs, and still satisfy something like, say $f(\beta) = g(\beta) + 1$ for all $\beta \in (0,1)$?

Comment: I think you're confused by the "for all $\beta$". You're supposed to pick a single, fixed-but-arbitrary beta, and then consider the map $E_{\beta}$. So you're looking for two functions that disagree at that single beta, but are very close when measured with that metric. As you suspect, the situation you consider in your last paragraph is impossible.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant- for any arbitrary $\beta$ in (0,1). Since f, g are supposed to be in $\mathcal C^0$, I don't see how they can differ at just one point for me to show that they are discontinuous.

Comment: That being said, I'm not too sure how to use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity to prove the statement either.

Comment: Fix $\beta\in (0,1)$. Let $f\equiv 0$.  Fix $0<\mu<\beta$ and let $$g(x)= \max\{0, 1- \frac{1}{\mu}|x-\beta|\}.$$  So $g$ is a function that's a triangle around $\beta$ and then drops (rapidly and linearly) to $0$ and stays $0$. Then $f(\beta)=0$, $g(\beta)=1$, and $d(f,g)$ is small (compute it). The idea is that the pointwise value at $\beta$ can be far apart, while $d$ measures how far apart functions are "on average," so they can be as far apart as we want at a point while being close on average over $[0,1]$.

Comment: To keep it simple, I should have said $0<\mu<\min \{\beta, 1-\beta\}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks! So at $\beta$, the functions can be arbitrarily close depending on the choice of $\mu$, but their difference of evaluations at that point is always 1, so choosing any $\epsilon<1$ would work